# How to combine two columns (a simple multiplication and addition) from a .csv file to a new one using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, data-science

I am new to programming and this seems like an easy one but I do not have experience so I need help. Thank you

So, I am doing an NBA themed task in which I need to make a column (feature) called TOTAL_GAME_TIME from PERIOD and GAME_CLOCK. I converted GAME_CLOCK to seconds so I now need to somehow multiplicate every period with 12 and add game clock to it so I can get total game time left in the game.

We are using a .csv file and the code is in Python. Head looks like this:
[Top 5 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjMRp.png)

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can access each column of your data frame through the name of e column:

```
yourDf["columnName"]
```

therefore, you can calculate the new feature you need.ofcourse, you have to be careful about the data types. the code you need is something like this

```
new_feature=my_file["PERIOD"]*12+my_file["GAME_CLOCK"]
```

also, you can add this new feature to your data frame exactly the same way you retrieve a new column from your data frame:

```
yourDf["newFeaureName"]
```

hope it helps you